# How to get my report to stop downloading in vue

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to create a link where I can download an excel file. The problem is, is that I have a job that will create
the excel file and I need to wait for that job to finish.
The code that I've written in the front end does do what I need it to do, but even after I'm able to download the excel
Also I noticed that in my dev tools under network after the inital request then it keeps saying `disk cache`
file the code still keeps executing and doesn't stop.
Here is my vue file

```
<template>
    <div class="card" style="width: 100%;">
        <div class="card-body">
            <ul>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link text-success downloadReport" @click="downloadReport">
                        <i v-if="!showSpinner" class="fas fa-file-excel"></i>
                        <i v-if="showSpinner" class="fa-solid fa-spinner fa-spin-pulse"></i>
                        Report
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: [],
        data() {
            return {
                pollingInterval: null,
                showSpinner: false
            }
        },
        mounted() {

        },
        methods: {
            downloadReport() {
                this.pollingInterval = setInterval(this.checkCondition, 2000);
            },
            async checkCondition() {
                this.showSpinner = true;
                const response = await axios.get("/download/report"); 
                if(response.data !== '')
                {
                    clearInterval(this.pollingInterval);
                    const link = document.querySelector('.downloadReport');
                    link.href = "/download/report";
                    link.click();

                    this.showSpinner = false;
                }
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

My Controller function

```
public function downloadReport()
{
    $report = reportService()->downloadReport('FullReport', request()->user());
    return $report;
}
```

My downloadReport function

```
public function downloadReport(string $report, User $user)
{   
    ExcelReport::dispatch('FullReport', $user);
    $cache = Cache::get('FullReport-'.$user->id);

    if(!is_null($cache))
    {
        $path = $cache;
    }else{
        $path = '';
    }

    return response()->download($path);
}
```

My ExcelReport Job

```
public function handle()
{
    $cacheKey = $this->reportName.'-'.$this->user->id;

    $report = excelReportService()->getFullReport($this->reportName, $this->user);
    Cache::put($cacheKey, $report);
}
```

Comment: It's an unconventional, possibly flawed, strategy. I would possibly rethink it in a way where you only need to await the axios call once. What exactly prevents awaiting the combined length of preparing + downloading the file? Why does `/download/report` need to return an empty string when the download is not ready instead of continuing to wait?  Can you show how the endpoint works?

Comment: @yoduh - I've updated my question to include what happens on the backend